# preview xlsx,docx etc. file blob url in iframe without download using angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, typescript

I am not able to preview xlsx,docx file blob url in iframe tag.I am also try with base64 string but not suucess.please help me to preview these files into the iframe tag.I refer ngx-doc-viewer but it not show preview.
bellow is my code:
<iframe  width="100%" height="500" [src]="docData" frameborder="0">
url = blobUrl;
this.docData= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);

Answer (score 0):

You can use sheetjs npm package and refer to this below link for an example of how to use it.

[Angular Preview Excel](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-preview-excel)

[XLSX NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

Comment: I have blob url that is come from backend ,no file .this blob url generate from s3 bucket url ,so how I can show this url.actually my problem is s3 bucket url is not show on frontend hence we generate blob url and try to show xlsx file on html

Comment: I guess convert blob to base64 and try it

Comment: I try but file is download but not preview

Comment: Can you provide your code on how you are doing?